# Sorry, for some reason PowerPoint couldn't load the IguanaTex add-in?

Tags: powerpoint, iguanatex

I followed the link to add latex equation to powerpoint

as shown and described here

[image: Point couldn]

In terms of download, I followed this link

http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/download.html

Everything was working fine but then things stop working and I do not know the reason behind it. Did anyone come across this problem?

Comment: I can't help but feel you will have better luck asking at the IguanaTeX Google Group, considering there are a grand total of 2 answered questions here about that particular software.

Comment: Is this on topic for this site? Does the addon actually use TeX? I ask because most of them don't .... Either way, I suspect @WillieWong is right.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to put the add-in file (in my case, `IguanaTex_v1_58.ppam`) in the following directory:

`$USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns`, where `$USER` is usually something like `C:\Users\<username>`.

This seems to be (by default) a directory where PowerPoint is less strict about security. **Of course, this means you should be careful and only put add-ins here that you really trust**.